# Angular2,Ionic2: How to store data in a mobile and retrieve it?

Tags: typescript, mobile, ionic2, local-storage, angular2-services

I'm developing a mobile application using Angular2 and Ionic2 frameworks. The app is basically an examination app where the user is asked to take an exam using the app. So my requirement is that it should be working even offline i.e without internet connectivity. I was searching for possible choices and found that we can store the contents of the exam on the user's device. But I want to know how can I do it ?

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use native storage, check this from the ionic documentation.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/

You need to install the Cordova plugin, import it, add it to the constructor, and then you can use this to save info

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
    .then(
        () => console.log('Stored item!'),
        error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
     );
```

And this to get info

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('myitem')
    .then(
        data => console.log(data),
        error => console.error(error)
     );
```

But please refer to the link and see the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. But I want to know if it is possible to store JSON format contents. And I also want to know how to save the answers of the user. Should I let the user always download the exam and take the test ?  Also my questions are in the form of objects. Is it okay to use to native plugin ?

Comment: Yes, you can save json, `'myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'}`. Explain more about the second question please

Comment: Should I make the user download the exam before he attempts it or how should it be done ? Will the answers the user has given be saved along with the exam in native storage?I'm so sorry for many doubts. But I'm completely new to this concept.Thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends in what do you want to achieve. You can download the exam questions and save them with the nativeStorage, with an id for that exam. You can have a pretty big json without problems!

Comment: All I want to achieve is that the user should be able to take the test even if there is no internet connectivity once he/she has started the test. Suppose user has lost the connectivity he should still be able to take the test and the answers should be stored somewhere till they get updated in the server after the internet connectivity is back. I want to know when should I let the user download the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nativeStorage, but it will only work on cordova platform (Either with ionic run or ionic emulate, but not with ionic serve)

My solution to this was creating a StorageProvider with ionic g provider, in which I created the methods: "setItem, getItem"

```
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage'


import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the StorageProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
@Component({
  providers: [Platform, NativeStorage]
})
export class StorageProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http, private platform: Platform, private nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {
    console.log('Hello StorageProvider Provider');
  }

  setStorage(storageId: string, data: Object){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject)=>{
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        return this.nativeStorage.setItem(storageId, data).then(res=>{
          resolve(res);
        }).catch(err=>{
          reject(err);
        });
      } else {
        resolve(localStorage.setItem(storageId, JSON.stringify(data)))
      }
    })
  }

  getStorage(storageId: string){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject)=>{
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')){
          this.nativeStorage.getItem(storageId).then(res=>{
            resolve(res);
          }).catch(err=>{
            reject(err);
          })
      } else {
        resolve(localStorage.getItem(storageId))
      }
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. But I want to know if it is possible to store JSON format contents. And I also want to know how to save the answers of the user. Should I let the user always download the exam and take the test ?

Comment: I've around 200 questions. Can I still use Nativestorage. I've read something about file plugin. Will that be of any use ?

Comment: Yes, you save JSON objects with the setStorage function, for example you need to do this to save an exam.

storageProvider.setItem("physicsExam", {"questions":[]};

Then when you want to get it you would go arround doing

storageProvider.getItem("physicsExam")

Comment: I didn't understand the second question though.

Comment: My doubt is if it is possible to store exams containing as many as 200 questions. Should I make the user download the exam before he attempts it or how should it be done ? I'm so sorry for many doubts. But I'm completely new to this concept. Thanks a lot for the answers

Comment: I couldn't find anything on the size limitations of NativeStorage, as far as i've read, there's no such limitation for Android devices. However, I would restrain from saving high amounts of data in the users device, unless you explain them that beforehand. Why isn't storing it in a external database an option?

Comment: Thank you. External database as in ? Something like sql lite ? I'm worried about its storage capacity.Could you please tell me if i should download the test before the user attempts it or only when the internet connectivity is not there ? I'm confused here. Because if the internet is not there then the user cannot download the test which means he cannot take the test.

Comment: No, I meant mongodb for example. How are you supposed to check for the results of the test with no internet connectivity? Also, internet access is really common so it's not a normal issue to look into unless you are developing a game. Separating data from the app also makes it more scalable, since if at some point you decide to add more stuff to it, storing everything inside the users device might end up being something impossible. What kinds of tests are these?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use MongoDB? The requirement is that the user should be able to continue his test even if suddenly the internet connectivity is lost. After he is done with the test,his answers should be saved along with the questions somewhere on his device. Once the internet connectivity is back, this should be sent to the server. This is exactly what I want to do. Thanks so much. I want to know which is better ? MongoDB or native storage ?

These are normal MCQ questions with 4 choices for each question. The test can be related to anything.But the questions are MCQ only.

Comment: As for if the connectivty is lost, you could save the answers the user already added in native storage, then when internet is back send them to the server. The server should actually be an API connecting with mongodb. You can search for more information on mongodb in google, sorry but this is getting kinda off-topic. Hope I was able to help though.

Comment: You are the only person who is able to help me. My server runs on tomcat and has APIs through which I receive and send data. Can't I achieve this using only native storage ? Do I really need to use MongoDB ?